# Is it possible to display a flat database table in a hierarchical unordered list?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a database table that is laid out like this:

```
Business     Phone        City       State         Country

Baker      12345678    CityName 1  StateName 1   CountryName 1
Mason      91834919    CityName 2  StateName 2   CountryName 1
Welder     58149918    CityName 3  StateName 1   CountryName 1
Painter    48194918    CityName 4  StateName 3   CountryName 2
Chef       95982848    CityName 5  StateName 4   CountryName 3
Vendor     96928248    CityName 1  StateName 1   CountryName 1
```

I would like to display this table in an html list like this:

```
 CountryName 1
    - StateName 1
        * CityName 1
            * Vendor | 9692824
            * Baker | 12345678
        * CityName 3
            * Welder | 58149918 
    - StateName 2
        * CityName 2
            * Mason | 91834919 
- CountryName 2
    - StateName 3
        * CityName 4
            * Painter | 48194918
- CountryName 3
    - StateName 4
        * CityName 5
            * Chef | 95982848
```

In the end, this database table will be very large with many businesses added over time. I am having a hard time even visualizing where to begin with this.

My question first:

- Is this even possible with the way that my table is laid out?
- If yes, how would I even begin to populate a list like this?

I'm new to PHP and mysql, but am pretty quickly wrapping my head around it. I think I just need an example or some direction to get me started here.

---

If possible, could I see an example of the PHP that would be required to input these values into a list like this?

---

I've asked a new question, as I would like to see a more direct example of how this is accomplished: [How can I rewrite my PHP & MySQL to group my HTML list by equal column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194009/how-can-i-rewrite-my-php-mysql-to-group-my-html-list-by-equal-column-values)

Comment: Do you have the option to rewrite your schema?

Comment: @ElGuapo Yes, I could. It is not something I have done before though.

Comment: I'm not a php programmer but this would be simple in ColdFusion.  The first step would be to make sure your sql ended with "order by country, state, city, business".  I suspect that would also be true with php.

Comment: based on your tags, you're also using php, so your sql query will look like what jeroen said with the order by, however in php you will then loop through the results using several nested for loops and that should get you the format you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple actually.  When you are querying your DB and are working with the result set, you simply load the data into a multi-dimensional array.  So something like this:

```
$final_array = array()
while($row = /* Your DB row fetch logic here */) {
    $row_object = new stdClass();
    $row_object->business = $row->business;
    $row_object->phone = $row->phone;
    $final_array[$row->country][$row->state][$row->city] = $row_object;
}
```

This gives you nested array of objects that is easily addressable by whatever combination of of country/state/city you like.

Now, you may also consider splitting your phone/city/state/country data into separate table with a 1 to many relationship with business if you want to accomodate a business having multiple locations in a normalized fashion.

Once you have this data, outputting to a tree/list structure shuould be pretty straightforward. Something like

```
foreach ($final_array as $country => $country_data) {
    // output $country and start a <ul> whatever you want HTML to look like
    foreach($country_data as $state => $state_data) {
        // output $state and start another list
        foreach($state_data as $city => $city_data) {
            // output $city and start another list
            foreach($city_data as $business_obj) {
                // output $business_obj->business and $business_obj->phone
            }
            // close city list
        }
        // close state list
    }
    // close country list
}
```

Comment: @JakeGould You may be right. I added a brief sample on how this could be approached.

Comment: @MikeBrant Thank you. I was able to understand and make use of this example in speeding up my learning and achieving my end goal with this project. Really appreciate the quick help here.

Comment: @user3380795 No problem. I will note that the approach I have shown here was done to give you a simplified example.  If your DB has a lot of rows, such that building this entire array structure in memory is too memory intensive, you should consider taking an approach like that mentioned by jeroen.  In that approach your would order the DB result set by country/state/name, and as you iterate through each row of the result set, you would look for changes in the values for these fields to determine if you need to close/open new HTML elements (i.e. lists) accordingly.

Comment: @MikeBrant I used your example as well as another example on another question and a bit of what jeroen suggested together, to understand this technique, and came up with a piece of code that outputs perfectly for all my rows. It is a very fast script, although if this database gets substantially larger, I may have to revisit this and try to do some optimization. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

With the table structure you have, you could do:

- Add an `ORDER BY` clause: `ORDER BY CountryName, StateName, CityName`;
- Keep track of the current country-, state- and city names as you are going through the results;
- Add one or more of your headers when any of these variables change.

Comment: Could you elaborate some on what you mean by keeping tracking of the current country-,state-, and city names? Would that be something in PHP?

Comment: It would indeed be something done in php.  You would use variables with names like CurrentCountry, CurrentState, etc.