# How can I rewrite my PHP & MySQL to group my HTML list by equal column values?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a database table that looks like this:

```
Business     Phone        City       State         Country

Baker      12345678    CityName 1  StateName 1   CountryName 1
Mason      91834919    CityName 2  StateName 2   CountryName 1
Welder     58149918    CityName 3  StateName 1   CountryName 1
Painter    48194918    CityName 4  StateName 3   CountryName 2
Chef       95982848    CityName 5  StateName 4   CountryName 3
Vendor     96928248    CityName 1  StateName 1   CountryName 1
```

I have this PHP and MySQL generating an unordered list on my webpage:

```
<?$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","testdb");
 $db = mysql_select_db("table",$con);
 $get=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Sheet1 ORDER BY country,state,region,city ASC");
  $result = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
  $result .= "<ul class='tree'><li>" . $row['country'] . "<ul><li>" . $row['state'] . "<ul><li>" . $row['region'] . "<ul><li>" . $row['city'] . "<ul><li>" . $row['business'] . " | Phone #: " . $row['phone'] . "</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>";
}?>
```

And this is my html:

```
<?php echo $result; ?>
```

It outputs like this:

```
 CountryName 1
    - StateName 1
        * CityName 1
            * Vendor | 9692824
 CountryName 1
    - StateName 1
        * CityName 1
            * Baker | 12345678
 CountryName 1
    - StateName 1
        * CityName 3
            * Welder | 58149918
 CountryName 1
    - StateName 2
        * CityName 2
            * Mason | 91834919
 CountryName 2
    - StateName 3
        * CityName 4
            * Painter | 48194918
```

I would like it to output like this:

```
 CountryName 1
    - StateName 1
        * CityName 1
            * Vendor | 9692824
            * Baker | 12345678
        * CityName 3
            * Welder | 58149918 
    - StateName 2
        * CityName 2
            * Mason | 91834919 
 CountryName 2
    - StateName 3
        * CityName 4
            * Painter | 48194918
 CountryName 3
    - StateName 4
        * CityName 5
            * Chef | 95982848
```

What changes must I make to accomplish this?

I gathered that this is much more complicated than what I have currently written out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you build the list, you should group them accordingly first (as your structure shows), from then you can build the list. Consider this example:

```
<?php

$original_data = array();
$link = new MySQLI('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
// normal select
$query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM Sheet1 order by country, state, city');
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $original_data[] = $row;
}

$ordered_data = array();
foreach($original_data as $key => $value) {
    // group them
    $ordered_data[$value['country']][$value['state']][$value['city']][] = $value;
}

?>

<!-- print them accordingly -->
<?php foreach($ordered_data as $country => $state_values): ?>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $country; ?></li>
        <?php foreach($state_values as $state => $city_values): ?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $state; ?></li>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($city_values as $city => $value): ?>
                        <li><?php echo $city; ?></li>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($value as $index => $element): ?>
                                <li><?php echo $element['Business'] . ' | ' . $element['Phone']; ?></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
        </ul>
        <?php endforeach; ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vPLxS9)

Comment: Thank you for this example. The nesting of "li"s and "ul"s wasn't quite right, but I was able to understand the example fully and it really helped me to reach my end goal. I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all records of the database, so it litteraly copies all rows and represents it like that to you. You have to give it the right order. Look at multidimensional arrays: [PHP multidimensional array from database results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396831/php-multidimensional-array-from-database-results)

Once you've gived it the right order with the proper if-else statements it should solve your problem.

Comment: Could you explain further with an example? I am learning these techniques as I go and find it much simpler to understand with an example. How do I give it the right order? I've attempted to set up this multidimensional array, but I don't understand how to actually plug that data into a <ul> in my html.